Explanation of trade half life in Almgren-Chriss paper
In Section 2.3 of Almgren, Robert, and Neil Chriss. "Optimal execution of portfolio transactions." Journal of Risk 3 (2001): 5-40 the authors define the half-life of a trade as $\theta \equiv 1/\kappa$ and note that it is exactly the amount of time it takes to deplete the portfolio by a factor of $e$.
Eq(17) derives the amount of inventory remaining at a trading time $t$ to be
$$
\frac{\sinh(\kappa(T - t))}{\sinh(\kappa T)} X.
$$
However, setting $t = \theta \equiv 1 / \kappa$ in the above does not yield $X / e$.
I suspect I am misinterpreting the claim and seek some guidance to set me straight.
Thank you!
